# Regex do not match if starts with a character

Tags: java, regex

I am developing a RegEx to detect SELECT statements in a piece of code. I have developed the following RegEx:

`(?i:SELECT ([a-zA-Z0-9\s ,*~()=<>@#_&'\"-])*)\.`

Basically catches everything that start with `SELECT` and ends with a `.` which is the line terminator (and they can be multi-line).

However, it also catches groups that start with `*` which is the comment symbol. Such as:

`*SELECT * FROM TABLE.`

I did try to put a negative lookahead `(?!\*)` but it still captures the SELECT statement.

What should I add to my RegEx for it not to capture the SELECT statements that start with `*`.

Edit:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\s*)(?i:SELECT ([a-zA-Z0-9\\s ,*~()=<>@#_&'\"-])*)\\.");
Matcher m = p.matcher(code);
while(m.find())
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: This regex works fine when using `String#matches()`.  Can you show us the actual Java code you are using?  You might consider adding boundary markers `^` and `$`, but that depends on how you are using the regex.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, I added `^(\\s*)` but it doesn't match any of the SELECT statements. I'm using JAVA and Pattern/Matcher.

Comment: As already asked some time ago, include your actual code.  Regex behaves differently in Java depending on which API you are using.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, added the code I currently have. Can't add the code inside the while as it is a project code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *Negative LookAhead*, you can use [*Negative LookBehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Just place `(?<!\*)` before the word `SELECT`

*Regex*

```
(?i:(?<!\*)SELECT ([a-zA-Z0-9\s ,*~()=<>@#_&'\"-])*)\.
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/slYYUK/1)

Comment: Hi, is it not possible to do a negative lookbehind with `*` quantifier? Like `(?<!\*\s*)`?

Comment: @KawamotoTakeshi In regex, `*` mean zero or more characters. You're right that it can't be used with negative lookbehind. But we mean literally `*` and NOT zero or more characters. That's why I placed backslash `\ ` before `*` which mean literally a `*`.

Comment: Note: Negative lookbehind might not be supported on all browsers

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for something that starts with SELECT, anchor it to the beginning with a ^ like this:

```
^SELECT[ ]{1,1}[a-zA-Z0-9*' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!\*)(?i:SELECT ([a-zA-Z0-9\s ,*~()=<>@#_&'\"-])*)\.
```

add the ^

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel comfortable using lookarounds, you can just explicitly check that each `SELECT` statement to be captured is either the start of the string, or is preceded by some non asterisk character.  Consider the following pattern:

```
(?:^|[^*])(SELECT (?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\s ,*~()=<>@#_&'\"-])*?)\\.
```

**Code:**

```
String input = "SELECT * FROM table_one. hello world blah *SELECT * FROM table_two. blah ";
       input += "SELECT * FROM table_three.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^|[^*])(SELECT (?:[a-zA-Z0-9\\s ,*~()=<>@#_&'\"-])*?)\\.");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(mix.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
SELECT * FROM table_one
SELECT * FROM table_three
```